# How to move to the next entry in an array if the first IF is false?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a user tool where a customer's first name is to be put in one column and their last name in the next column.

Many users put the full name in the first column.

I'm trying to ensure the second column has data if the first column has data. If the second doesn't, I want to throw up a message box and change a variable value to 1, then stop the function. IF both have data, check the next cell in the column.

My current code (I think) checks if the first cell is blank, and if it is not checked if the second cell is blank. If the second cell is blank, it throws up a msgbox and fills a variable. This variable is checked once the loop is over (in a different module) to stop the follow-on processes if its value is greater than 1.

<strike>I tried adding an `End If` but that stops it from working.</strike>

```
Public Sub namesCheck()
    Dim nameRange() As Variant
    nameRange = Array("C10:C500") 'add all addresses here

    Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In nameRange
        If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Input").Range(cell)) = False Then
            If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Input").Range(cell).Offset(0, 1)) = True Then
                MsgBox "Please format names correctly."
                checkNet = 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

<strike>I get that currently, there's no instruction for what to do if the first cell is empty but I'm not sure how to put that in and I figured the Else takes care of that? If the first if is True, then it wouldn't do the second If and skip to the end?</strike>

Currently, I'm getting 'Next without For' error which I'm guessing is related to the second If statement as I have a similar loop with a single If that works just fine.

I've ended the first If statement which I wasn't doing before. Now the code does nothing. I've tested with a couple of correct rows (data in both columns) and one incorrect row (data just in the first column) and it doesn't bring up the msgbox.

Could it be that my second If isn't doing its job of checking the next cell over from the one it just checked? Is there another reason it's not picking up the empty cells in the second column?

Comment: Besides the obvious mistake of missing the `End If` I wonder what your goal is here. If you want to loop through your array of ranges, you might risk exiting the `For...` loop too soon (not checking all ranges in `NameRange`.

Answer (score 3):

Proper indentation would help identify the error.  Consider your code with indentation:

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Input").Range(Cell)) = False Then
   If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Input").Range(Cell).Offset(0, 1)) = True Then
      MsgBox "Please format names correctly."
      nameNet = 1
   Else
      Exit For
   End If
```

It should now be obvious what has to happen to fix the code.  Simply add an `End If` as the last line of code.

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Input").Range(Cell)) = False Then
   If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Input").Range(Cell).Offset(0, 1)) = True Then
      MsgBox "Please format names correctly."
      nameNet = 1
   Else
      Exit For
   End If
End If
```

Now moving on to the problem you are trying to solve.  Setting a break point and stepping through the code reveals you are only looping one time and the specified conditions are not satisfied.  Assuming you are looking to spin down column C from row 10 to 500, I would structure your code like this:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim nameRange() As Variant
    nameRange = Array("C10:C500") 'add all addresses here

    Dim nr As Variant
    Dim cell As Variant

    For Each nr In nameRange  'assuming you may add more items to the array
        For Each cell In Worksheets("Input").Range(nr)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) And IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 1)) Then
                MsgBox "Please format names correctly."
                checkNet = 1
                Exit Sub  'as soon as you find a problem you are done
            End If
        Next cell
    Next nr
End Sub
```

This likely can be written in a more efficient manner by one of the Excel experts on this site, but not knowing the entire scope of your problem I'll not change your code too much.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the reply I've added another End If as suggested (and will be sure to indent my code properly from now on) but it's not working. Please see my edit and see if you can help further.

Comment: @TomCrow Please see my revised answer.